# Modeling cyclic processes when timing is hard

Tags: regression, distributions, modeling

I have a collection of timestamps for a process that is essentially cyclic:
$$
t_{n+1}-t_n = k + E_n
$$
where $k$ is an absolute (unknown) constant and $E_n$ is an error term, small compared to $k$.

The main issue with my data is that it’s hard to determine exactly when the process occurs (there’s no clean cutoff), so there is significant measurement error compared to the intrinsic variability.

I’d like to get a handle on how large this effect is and tease out these different effects. What are good methods? I have a small amount of difficult-to-obtain data, so making good use of it will be key.

1. Because the detection of an event is not hard (just it’s precise timing), the differences $t_{n+2}-t_n$, etc., will show less variability. Of course this also rolls in the actual errors I’m interested in.
2. I considered moving the endpoints $t_n$ around to see how far I could reduce the errors — that should give a lower bound on the intrinsic variability. Any thoughts on how to do this, or a better approach?

Comment: Could you describe the data you actually have?  It sounds like you have processed them to estimate "when the process occurs."  The issue with that is that all subsequent results depend on the accuracy of that pre-processing and will suffer from the loss of information that ensues.  It is plausible, at least, that a direct attack on your problem that begins with the original data might be more effective and precise.

Comment: @whuber All the data I have are the timestamps. I can reasonably trust that all the events are detected (and even without trust, an omission would show up in the data very clearly, with a gap close to $2k$ instead of $k$) but that's about it.

Comment: Okay. But that makes it difficult to understand your first point. To the extent there is a *systematic additive* error in the timestamp measurements, taking their differences will reduce it. At the same time, however, it will tend to *increase* any random error, because (assuming any two timestamp measurements are uncorrelated), $\operatorname{Var}(t_n-t_m)=\operatorname{Var}(t_n)+\operatorname{Var}(t_m).$ For instance, when the measurement variance is constant, taking differences *doubles* that. Have you actually observed "less variability" in these differences, or do you just suppose that?

Comment: @whuber I must not have communicated this well, because a systemic additive error in the timestamps would be completely invisible to me since I’m only looking at the differences. If I adjust one timestamp I’ll make one interval longer and one shorter, and that could give a dataset with lower (or higher) variance. The mean would be unaffected unless I change an endpoint (which doesn’t seem quite fair).

Comment: I still haven't any idea what you're trying to ask. I trace this difficulty to the question itself, which is "how large this effect is." What is "this effect"? The *spirit* of the question seems to be to identify components of variability: namely, "measurement error" and "intrinsic variability" and perhaps (it's unclear) some kind of cyclic behavior.  It isn't at all evident you have data that would permit you to do that, if all you have are time stamps. That leaves us with your initial formula, which is the simplest possible regression setting: estimate $k$ as the mean time difference.

Comment: @whuber I can measure the mean pretty well. I would like to improve my estimation of the variance. I suggested an idea for getting a lower bound, which I have reason to believe would be closer to the true value (if I knew the true value $t_n$ rather than just $t_n+e_n$). I’d like to know (1) if this is a bad idea, (2) if there are better ideas for bounding the variance, and (3) how to implement my idea or others.